# GPO errors filling up event viewer

Tags: windows-server-2003

there have been a few issues with the server i have been working on i check the event viewer and it is filled with the errors below i was not sure how to go about fixing this i looked in the path where the file is and it is there

`Windows cannot access the file gpt.ini for GPO CN={31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9},CN=Policies,CN=System,DC=ISPHOME,DC=NET. The file must be present at the location <\\isphome.net\\sysvol\ISPHOME.NET\Policies\{31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9}\gpt.ini>. (The network location cannot be reached. For information about network troubleshooting, see Windows Help. ). Group Policy processing aborted.`

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Dimitri>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : ispserver
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : ISPHOME.NET
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Unknown
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : ISPHOME.NET

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 3:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) PRO/100 VE Network Connection #2

   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-07-E9-AA-3E-C3
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.50
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 127.0.0.1
```

****dcdiag /c /v is below****

```
         Summary of test results for DNS servers used by the above domain contro
llers:

            DNS server: 192.168.1.1 (<name unavailable>)
               All tests passed on this DNS server
               This is a valid DNS server

            DNS server: 192.168.1.50 (<name unavailable>)
               All tests passed on this DNS server
               This is a valid DNS server
               Name resolution is funtional. _ldap._tcp SRV record for the fores
t root domain is registered

         Summary of DNS test results:

                                            Auth Basc Forw Del  Dyn  RReg Ext
               ________________________________________________________________
            Domain: ISPHOME.NET
               ispserver                    PASS FAIL PASS PASS PASS PASS n/a

         ......................... ISPHOME.NET failed test DNS
```

Comment: dcdiag /c /v please

Comment: first time back in this office since last week, but i have it posted above

Answer (score 2):

The error says "cannot access the file gpt.ini for..." ... so can you access it?  Open up Windows Explorer on that client and browse to `\\ISPHOME\Sysvol` and keep drilling down to the GUID in the error message that represents the GPO that is causing that error for you.

Is the file there?  Can you read it?  If not, why not?  Name resolution?  File permissions?  Firewalls?

The first thing I see wrong in your ipconfig output is that your primary DNS server should never be 127.0.0.1. Unless you have one and only one domain controller in the entire domain and you are logged on to that domain controller.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming by `\\<DOMAIN\` you meant `\\isphome.net\` in that error message, what you have is a dead or malfunctioning domain controller.

Check, for each of your DCs, that you can access the `\\sysvol` share on each, and that they all contain the same contents.  Access to this share and its consistency is absolutely required for correct AD operation.

If you can access them, it's possible that you may have DCs which were removed from the domain improperly (without `dcpromo` being run on them to remove them from the domain before they were taken offline).  In this case you will have to manually purge them.

Failing this, it is possible that sysvol was corrupted for one reason or another and lacks the GPO definition.  If this is the case, delete the affected GPO (`CN={31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9},CN=Policies,CN=System,DC=ISPHOME,DC=NET`) and write and apply it again.  The unique name field in each GPO's properties tab will contain its GUID.